# Using transcludeFn in angular components

Tags: angularjs

Is it true, that I cannot customize transclusion in angular components (angular 1.5)? The task I want to solve is passing a template to a component using transclusion and make it able to use "in-the-component" variables. Like this:

```
<my-items-component items="$ctrl.items">
    <div>{{::item.description}}</div>
</my-items-component>
```

Where item supposed to be put into my-items-component documentation, and used to customize the item presentation inside the component.

I was able to do this with directives, using transcludeFn function, but it seems there are no arguments passed to $postLink component hook.

So, should I use a directive for this or there's another approach?

Answer (score 4):

To use tansclusion in AngularJS 1.5 components you need first to enable tarnsclusion in your component by using `transclude: true`, then use `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>` in your component template.

I have created a sample pen as an example http://codepen.io/fadihania/pen/bwpdPq

Comment: I know, how to use transclusion. I need to use custom transclusion (bind the transcluded content to another scope). I used transcludeFn in a directive link function before.

Comment: What about put on a jsbin or plunker your try with transcludeFn?

Answer (score 2):

I've found an answer.

[Access $scope of Component within Transclusion in AngularJS 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580610/access-scope-of-component-within-transclusion-in-angularjs-1-5)

This worked with my problem. My example:

```
<my-custom-component>
  <input model="$parent.$ctrl.name">
</my-custom-component>
```

Then in my component now I have "name". I hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways of solving  your problem

1. to place all our html inside component template definition

   ```
   app.component('myItemComponent', new myItemComponentConfig());
    function myItemComponentConfig() {
    this.controller = componentController;
    this.template = '<div>{{::item.description}}</div>',
    this.bindings = {
       this.bindings = {
          items:'<'
        }
     };
    this.require = {};
   }
   ```

use it like this :

```
 <my-items-component items="$ctrl.items"></my-items-component>
```

2.use Ng-transclude to load child HTML of a component

```
app.component('myItemComponent', new myItemComponentConfig());
         function myItemComponentConfig() {
         this.controller = componentController;
         this.template = '<div></div>',
         this.bindings = {
           items:'<'
         };
         this.require = {};
         this.transclude:true;
        }
```

use it like this :

```
<my-items-component items="$ctrl.items">
    <div>{{::item.description}}</div>
</my-items-component>
```